# Highcharts pie chart plotting different values

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I'm making a highchart Pie chart and for some strange reason the data I tell it to display are different from what the pie chart shows.

Here's the code:

```
$('#container1').highcharts({
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Data'
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.2f}%</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: '#000000',
                onnectorColor: '#000000',
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.2f} %'
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Percent of Total Samples:',
        data: [
            ['Tf', 14.28],
            ['To', 5.71],
            ['Ts', 74.28]
        ]
    }]
});
```

here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3eL5eqgo/

Anybody have any insight into why this might be happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's showing different data than what you provide is because it's showing a percentage of the total. If your data added to 100 it would be the same but it doesn't.

Comment: Brilliant.  Thanks for that.  I hope to catch little things like this the more I work with this stuff.